# "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined " chat stops working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-customer-chat

I'm using fb customer chat ob my website and trying to basically  close the whole  chat when a user closes the chat window i managed to make a small code that achieves this.

```
function hide_facebook() {

var x = document.getElementById("fb-root");

x.style.display = "none";}FB.Event.subscribe('customerchat.dialogHide', hide_facebook());
```

When i run  FB.Event.subscribe('customerchat.dialogHide', hide_facebook());

on the console, the code works and chat hides.

but when i implement the code i get  " Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined"

also when i load the sdk myself  from

i checked the current sdk bundle and the function is right there i tried  adding the code below the customer chat script but nothing seems to work
when i try to include the sdk library myself the error disappears but the chat stops working, doesn't even load.

what could be causing this issue?

cause on the console i don't get any more errors so i have no clue.

Comment: You are calling FB before the SDK have loaded. When you are testing in the console it has loaded.

Comment: The code is placed below the sdk inport   so i don't think thats the issue

Comment: The SDK import code is async and it will call a callback when it is ready. You need to use the callback to know when it is ready